# What does "Creates a socket address from an IP address" mean?

Tags: java, sockets

I was reading the javadoc for InetSocketAddress at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ and was wondering what the following phrase means:

> Creates a socket address from an IP address and a port number.

What I want to do is create a socket on the local box that listens for incoming connections on the same port and begins communication with that client. I was using "localhost"/80 for the host name on my server, but netstat -l doesn't show anything listening on port 80.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: It creates a socket address, right, from an IP address and a port number. For "socket address," read "instance of the `InetSocketAddress` class."

Comment: Who downvoted this and recommended closure? What's wrong with this question?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Again, what does "from" mean? Does that mean it attempts to connect to a socket server on that port? If so, why not "to"?

Comment: @ The Thom: This is completely standard terminology for when you're constructing something *from* the arguments given to the constructor. "Using" may have been clearer, but I think if you [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html) it's clear that `InetSocketAddress`, itself, isn't a connection to anything. It's just an address, like `File` is an abstract name, not an actual file. (That latter, in my view, wasn't the best choice they could have made -- but they didn't ask me! :-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you need to create a ServerSocket.

From memmory: It is something like

```
ServerSocket mySocket =new ServerSocket(1234); // Listen on port 1234 on all network interfaces.

Socket incommingSocket=mySoccket.accept(); // Wait until a client connect. Once a client connect return the socket for the connection.
```

And then you can call getInputStream/getOutputStream on the incommingSocket object.